# Aggregating by count then getting middle buckets from elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

So I know how to get the top N by aggregation in elasticsearch, which is this:

```
query= {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_cat": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cat.keyword",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get, for example, the top 400th-500th buckets? I was linked to [range aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) on the elasticsearch reference but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Aggregation you cannot use "from" keyword.
There are two ways to perform pagination.

1. Partitions.

   ```
    "size":15
    "include": {
        "partition": 0,            <-- Trying to retrieve the first partition
        "num_partitions": 7        <-- Expecting 7 partitions (7*15 > 101 (total records))
      }
   ```
2. Composite aggregation
    It combines several aggregation in a single stream. In this you can only paginate linearly. ie you cannot just from page 1 to page 3

Comment: hi, are you saying that I cannot do this within elasticsearch?

Comment: you can use partitions (Point 1) . link for further referencehttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions